# App freezes when trying to send an object via a socket

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

Let me jump right in. Here's my Server class:

```
public class DTServer {

ServerSocket serverSocket;
ServerSocketHints serverSocketHints;
Socket socket;
InputStream inputStream;
OutputStream outputStream;
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

public DTServer(int port) {
    serverSocketHints = new ServerSocketHints();
    serverSocketHints.acceptTimeout = 0;

        serverSocket = Gdx.net.newServerSocket(
                Net.Protocol.TCP, port, serverSocketHints);

    socket = serverSocket.accept(null);
}

public Serialized receiveSerialized() {
    inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    try {
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    try {
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Serialized serialized = new Serialized();
    try {
        serialized = (Serialized) objectInputStream.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serialized;
}
}
```

And the Client class:

```
public class DTClient {

Socket socket;
SocketHints socketHints;
InputStream inputStream;
OutputStream outputStream;
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream;
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream;

public DTClient(String address, int port) {
    socketHints = new SocketHints();
    socketHints.connectTimeout = 3000;
    socketHints.keepAlive = true;
//        socketHints.trafficClass = 0x04; //IPTOS_RELIABILITY

    socket = Gdx.net.newClientSocket(
            Net.Protocol.TCP, address, port, socketHints);
}

public void sendSerialized(Serialized serialized) {
    inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    try {
        objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
    try {
        objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(serialized);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I create the server object like this:

```
public void startServer() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dtServer = new DTServer(32658);
            System.out.println("Server started and listening at port: 32658.");
        }
    }).start();
}
```

And then connect to it with other instance of the program:

```
public void connect() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            dtClient = new DTClient("127.0.0.1", 32658);
            System.out.println("Connected to server at 127.0.0.1:32658");

        }
    }).start();
}
```

And everything work swell until I try to receive the object I sent:

```
game.dtClient.sendSerialized(new Serialized(game.gameScreen.localPlayer));
//client side

Serialized s = (Serialized)game.dtServer.receiveSerialized();
//server side
```

Calling receiveSerialized method causes both app instances to freeze.

Answer (score 0):

Create the `ObjectOutputStream` before the `ObjectInputStream,` at both ends. Otherwise you can get a deadlock trying to read the object stream header.

You should also use the same object streams for the life of the socket, rather than a new pair per message.